# VueJS Requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have a VueJs app with a Laravel backend as the API.

When running locally the app works as expected with https, however when on the production server I get the `Requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint` message.

My server is on Digital Ocean, has been setup with RunCloud and has SSL enabled through LetsEncrypt.

The application can be viewed here: https://vehicletrader.sweney.co/#/

Please note at this stage theres is no authorization surrounding the API.

Any advice would help.

Comment: Might help to explicitly set the `baseURL` parameter https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config

Comment: Unfortunately the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slash `/` at the end of the request URL was the cause of this for me.

My axios call was a simple `axios.post('https://getShafiq.com/hello/')`.

Locally, it was working.

But on prod server behind CloudFlare, it would return `insecure XMLHttpRequest`.

What I noticed in the 'Network' tab of my browser's dev tools is that the URL is returning a `301 - Moved Permanently` and right after it, the error about the insecure endpoint.

I removed the `/` after `/hello` and boof, it works.